# C# Loop over all possible values, when not found increase value and continue

Tags: c#, string

I need to send a request for every supplier code to a webservice (i know that sounds crazy but the owner designed it this way).

The supplier code format is:

30X1X1XXXXX1

You can check what i did so far (github link: https://github.com/rareba/SiapWebServices_Library/blob/master/SiapWebServices_Library/SiapWebServicesFornitore.cs)

```
public static List<StructAnaFornitoreOut> Get_All_Suppliers(WebServicesFornitoreClient client, StructLogin loginCredentials, string showSuspended = "N", string searchType = "R")
    {
        var supplier_list = new List<StructAnaFornitoreOut>();
        var supplier_retrived = new StructAnaFornitoreOut
        {
            esito = new StructEsito
            {
                stato = "OK",
            }
        };

        int KO_Count = 0;
        int conto = 1;
        int sottoconto = 1;
        int codice = 0;
        string codFornitore = Generate_Supplier_Code_String(codice, sottoconto, conto);

        var search = new StructAnaFornitoreIn
        {
            IAnaFornitore = new StructAnaFornitore
            {
                codice = codFornitore
            },
            IAzione = "C",
            //vModRicerca = new string[] { "COD_FIS","PAR_IVA","ALT_SIS" }
        };
        while (KO_Count < 10)
        {
            while (KO_Count < 10)
            {
                while (KO_Count < 10)
                {
                    supplier_retrived = client.gestioneAnagraficaFornitore(loginCredentials, search);

                    if (supplier_retrived.esito.stato == "KO")
                    {
                        KO_Count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        supplier_list.Add(supplier_retrived);
                        codFornitore = Generate_Supplier_Code_String(codice, sottoconto, conto);
                        Console.WriteLine(codFornitore);
                        codice++;
                        search.IAnaFornitore.codice = codFornitore;
                    }
                }
                KO_Count = 0;
                sottoconto++;
            }
            KO_Count = 0;
            conto++;
        }

        return supplier_list;
    }

    // Returns a supplier code string increased by 1
    public static string Generate_Supplier_Code_String(int codice = 0, int sottoconto = 1, int conto = 1, string mastro = "30")
    {
        codice++;

        string string_conto = " ";
        string string_sottoconto = " ";
        string string_codice = "     ";

        if (conto > 9)
        {
            string_conto = "";
        }

        if (sottoconto > 9)
        {
            string_sottoconto = "";
        }

        if (codice > 9)
        {
            string_codice = "    ";
        }
        else if (codice > 99)
        {
            string_codice = "   ";
        }
        else if (codice > 999)
        {
            string_codice = "  ";
        }
        else if (codice > 9999)
        {
            string_codice = "  ";
        }
        else if (codice > 99999)
        {
            string_codice = " ";
        }
        else if (codice >= 999999)
        {
            string_codice = "";
        }

        string customercode = mastro + string_conto + conto + string_sottoconto + sottoconto + string_codice + codice;

        return customercode;
    }
```

However this doesn't work at all: it stops at supplier 30 1 1   100 and starts increasing sottoconto like there is no tomorrow.

The idea should be to do something like:
- Get the supplier data
- Increase codice by 1
- If for 10 times you get nothing (esito.status = "KO") then increase sottoconto and start again from codice = 1
- If after incresing sottoconto you still get nothing for 10 times then increase conto and start again from codice = 0

Comment: Why have you got "while (KO_Count < 10)" 3 times? The condition "if (codice > 9)" is true when codice > 99 and codice > 999 etc, so the other conditions will never fire. You should reverse the order of those if statements, i.e., with "if (codice >= 999999)" first and "else if (codice > 9)" last.

Comment: From your description you want 10 + 10 + 10 = 30, but your code is 10 * 10 * 10 = 1000.